# Multiple ports for a single application in jboss fuse

Tags: java, jboss, jetty, jbossfuse

Relatively new to jboss fuse. We have a requirement of running a single application on multiple ports. Is it practically possible? specify a range of port in config file.

I tried like cfg.port: 9000, 9001

but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to have the application's Camel routes that use those ports define them in their routes. The built-in Jetty listener is generally for shared web service endpoints using CXF and the management web console.